# QT - How to retrieve QVariant Values from combobox?

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qvariant

I'm using QVariant to store a object inside of a Qcombobox, This appears to work fine. This is the implementing code:

Add type to QVariant in header:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CDiscRecorder*)
```

pDiscRecorder Casted as CDiscRecorder:

```
CDiscRecorder* pDiscRecorder = new CDiscRecorder();
```

Then stored in the combobox

```
ui->cbDrives->addItem(QString::fromWCharArray(strName), QVariant::fromValue(pDiscRecorder));
```

The problem arises when I try to pull it out:

```
CDiscRecorder* discRecorder = this->ui->cbDrives->itemData(index).value<CDiscRecorder*>;
```

I receive the error:

```
error C3867: 'QVariant::value': function call missing argument list; use '&QVariant::value' to create a pointer to member
```

I tried to implement the hint in the error code to no avail, I have followed the thread [Add QObject in the combo box of Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586877/add-qobject-in-the-combo-box-of-qt) to implement this behavior, how can get my object back ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is giving you the hint that the argument list is missing - all you should need to do is add the brackets to tell it that you're trying to call the function. So change it to

```
CDiscRecorder* discRecorder = this->ui->cbDrives->itemData(index).value<CDiscRecorder*>();
```

And it should work. That's quite a long line, might be cleaner to break it out

```
QVariant variant = this->ui->cbDrives->itemData(index);
CDiscRecorder* discRecorder = variant.value<CDiscRecorder*>();
```